# Is it possible to pass two parameters to $http.post from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I do not have an issue constructing `$http.post` request with an object or single parameter, but in one particular case I need to pass 2 simple parameters, an integer and a string.

Normally I use:

```
 $http.post(url, id)
       .success(function (data, status, header) {
           $scope.result = data;

       })
       .error(function (data, status, header) {
           $scope.result = "Data: " + data +
               "<hr />status: " + status;
           console.log(header.responseText);
       });
```

But how can I modify it to pass two parameters?

I have tried creating an object with two properties and passing that object:

```
var inData = {
   id: id,
   param2: param2
}

$http.post(url, inData)
   .success(function (data, status, header) {
       $scope.result = data;

   })
   .error(function (data, status, header) {
       $scope.result = "Data: " + data +
           "<hr />status: " + status;
       console.log(header.responseText);
   });
```

But then I am not sure what to specify as a parameter in my Web API method that is passed in via `url` parameter.

Is that possible to pass in 2 separate parameters instead of passing in an object?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "two parameters"? What does the backend expect? You're not passing any parameter in the above code. You're passing id as the body, and angular will JSONify this id. You can pass any object, and it will do the same.

Comment: can't you just send the two parameters as an object?

Comment: the issue is that backend expects 2 parameters, an integer and a string

Answer (score 1):

> But then I am not sure what to specify as a parameter in my Web API method that is passed in via url parameter.

URL parameters are added to the `$http.post` method as part of the optional config object:

```
 var params = { name: value,
                name2: value2
              };
 $http.post(url, data, { params: params });
```

In the above example, the $http service will append `?name=value&name2=value2` to the URL. The `data` argument is placed in the body of the POST request. If the `data` argument is an object it will be transformed to a string using the default transformRequest function.

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post).